# Is it possible to narrow a discriminated union using an argument function with an inferred generic type?

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to write wrapper functions which (amongst other things) narrow the type of a union that is passed in as an argument based on a discriminator key and then pass it to a callback, narrowed. This is a minimal version of what I've tried:

```
interface Thing {
  key: 'bar'
  property: number
}

interface OtherThing {
  key: 'baz'
  property: string
}

type Things = Thing | OtherThing

type NarrowedThing<A, K> = A extends { 'key': K } ? A : never

const narrowingFunction = <K extends Things['key']>(thing: Thing, key: K, callback: (thing: NarrowedThing<Things, K>) => void) => {
  if(thing.key === key) {
    callback(thing) // Argument of type 'Thing' is not assignable to parameter of type NarrowedThing<Thing, K> | NarrowedThing<OtherThing, K>. Thing is not assignable to type 'NarrowedThing<OtherThing, K>
  }
}
```

Now I suspect from the error message that I'm going to be told that this is simply not possible, because it reads like the narrowing just doesn't work in this scenario. But I'd be really interested to know

- Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do or if not
- Why does this not work? (if there is a reason other than just 'TypeScript haven't implemented it')

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell, why exactly this code doesn't work. Generics are pretty complicated and narrowing down types with them is even more so, considering typescript doesn't know much about the types before the function is actually called. I can tell though, how to make it work: give typescript a hint on how to narrow down types. Basically you don't need to change anything in the code, only wrap this `thing.key === key` check into a type guard that will explicitly tell typescript "see, this `thing` is actually not simply a `Thing` but a `NarrowedThing<Things, K>`"

```
const isThingWithKey = <K extends Things['key']>(
  thing: Things, 
  key: K
): thing is NarrowedThing<Things, K> {
  return thing.key === key
}
```

Then use it

```
const narrowingFunction = <K extends Things['key']>(
  thing: Things, 
  key: K, 
  callback: (thing: NarrowedThing<Things, K>) => void
) => {
  if(isThingWithKey(thing, key)) {
    callback(thing)
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8CwAUMsgNYQCeAXMgOQBGcUtRJADlAPZvRjXIgArgFt60IgF8iRUJFiIUAeTDpoGbHlZlKNBnABeLYsg7de-AM5go2SdMJ8eaTCCwXkAXmcaAPsmWqUOqu9o4oAHJMXADuEAAmwVgAPACCADTIANIAfJ7IKcgQAB6QIHHuuHTkFLQ0mcgSyAD8%20cg0IBAAbuKERAicIFbIwBaJAOrAKpmUeUn1xaXl3q4WANq01bQAutkAFFoq2DSJFhla1XVEAJQ0h67D7pFQMfGJSScZOZ65d1gAdNVPB4vNV7P1BmABFFONFsAAxQQgBBgYADWbzEoQMruE7rTY7fbGX7HFxuM7GC5ZckkBBwAA2dMYCFINF2xOQTxeCVJ71Jpyy2Su32QnU4wDi12FBGMwBguxG40m6GmFDZpIy1SuQulJBp9MZiFIauwVy0UkIEiAA)

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your answer. That's not really what I was looking for; I'm aware of how to do this with a custom type guard anyway. I'm just curious to understand why (or if) it doesn't work when the key is passed into a generic function

Comment: Well, then I don't think there is a better answer than "this is not implemented (yet?)". Maybe you can find a deeper reason by exploring typescript source code to get some insights on how type narrowing works, particularly `checker.ts`, but it's a heck of a lot of code.